# Custom Domain on Deployment Slot

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I was able to add a custom domain to a Azure deployment slot on one web app, but when I tried to add one to another, I keep getting:

> The resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/xxx(xxxx)' under resource group 'Default-Web-WestEurope' was not found

*Where `xxx(xxxx)` is my web app name and deployment slot.

I've tried to remake the deployment slot, I've recreated the web app but still no luck.

Comment: Are you in the correct region?

Comment: How are you trying to add the custom domain? From portal.azure.com or from a Powershell or REST Api?

Comment: @ZainRizvi From portal.azure.com

Comment: @timothyclifford Yeah - I'm in the correct region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using the Azure Powershell using the following command:

`Set-AzureWebsite -Name "xxx(xxxx)" -HostNames @('custom.domain.com')`